# Error in loading an image from url in simple image php class

Tags: php, image

I am using a simple-image PHP class.
I tried to load  an image from a URL by using the `fromDataUri($uri)` function. 
Every time the function returns  **Invalid Data URI**. 
For example, I use this:

```
fromDataUri('https://static.pexels.com/photos/36753/flower-purple-lical-blosso.jpg')
```

But this code returns also with **invalid URI**.
If load any image from  a folder it works good.
So how can I solve this?
Here is the **[Simple Image Github Repository](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)**.

Comment: Well, you forgot to post the actual data URI. Maybe it is invalid?

Comment: please check out the question I have edited it. I want load an image to edit .where I used a php  class called 'simple image' calss. but I can't load  what;s the problem in loading I want to know this. thank you

Comment: It appears you did not yet fully understand what a data uri actually is. Please dive back into the documentation and examples.

Comment: thanks. now it is  clear to me. I have confusion in data uri and url . thank you

Answer (score 0):

because you provide wrong URI. Function `fromDataUri($uri)` requires data uri scheme as seen in it's implementation

```
...
    preg_match('/^data:(.*?);/', $uri, $matches);
        if(!count($matches)) {
          throw new \Exception('Invalid data URI.', self::ERR_INVALID_DATA_URI);
        }
...
```

and you passing http/https URI scheme.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I load an image from a link with this class and what is the difference between data uri and  http/https URI.

Comment: [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) check this link